# How to check if there are repeated numbers in a list

Tags: python

```
repeat=[1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,1,5,7,7]
```

how to check if there are any duplicates 2 or more using boolean operators with python.
Here is my code

```
repeat = set()
for x in one_sample:
    if x in repeat: 
        return True
    repeat.add(x)
return False
print(repeat)
```

Comment: Also you posted a code - what's wrong with it? Isn't it giving you the desired results? Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: BTW, your code is correct.

Comment: Your code is correct. Why are you posting this then?

Answer (score 1):

Code showing if there are duplicates and their values if there are:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU5LCoMwEN17itmZwHQR@kkreBIRETQYCElwYsFePh0DbZdlNjPvzfvEPS3Bn3N20EKn8IJXvKHGOz54FF8adV/RQVNY0zwJJ6tlpGHaIjE4@l0YaJkFE1YwyIv18LJRkOuak@oZcZ1qeimrQzM8R0c/N5oT6/9JwfJPSWGXuFqfRM0l4DBsaoRPIQQ@SjNO2ebCfUNlzm8)

```
l = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,1,5,7,7]
sl = sorted(l)
has_dups = any(f == s for f, s in zip(sl[:-1], sl[1:]))
dups_vals = sorted(set(f for f, s in zip(sl[:-1], sl[1:]) if f == s))
print('has dups:', has_dups, ', dups values:', dups_vals)
```

Outputs:

```
has dups: True , dups values: [1, 5, 7, 9]
```

Code works lazily, i.e. it sets `has_dups` to `True` (found duplicate) as soon as the very first duplicate is found in sorted array.

If input array is very large, then `numpy` can be used which is magnitude faster than pure Python. Next code implements same task using `numpy` (numpy needs to be installed once `python -m pip install numpy`):

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64082207#main.py)

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,1,5,7,7]
sa = np.sort(l)
has_dups = np.any(sa[:-1] == sa[1:])
dups_vals = sa[np.append(np.diff(
    np.insert((sa[:-1] == sa[1:]).astype(np.int8), 0, 0)
) == 1, False)]
print('has dups:', has_dups, ', dups values:', dups_vals)
```

Output is same:

```
has dups: True , dups values: [1 5 7 9]
```

And another even simpler `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,1,5,7,7]
vals, cnts = np.unique(l, return_counts = True)
has_dups = np.any(cnts > 1)
dups_vals = vals[cnts > 1]
print('has dups:', has_dups, ', dups values:', dups_vals)
```

Also just checking if there are any duplicates can be done using simple next code with `set()`:

```
l = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,1,5,7,7]
has_dups = len(set(l)) < len(l)
print('has dups:', has_dups)
```

outputs

```
has dups: True
```

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for boolean operators

```
repeat=[1,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,1,5,7,7]
repeat = sorted(repeat)
for i in range(len(repeat)-1):
    if repeat[i]==repeat[i+1]:
        return True
return False
```

Complexity O(nlog(n))

Comment: That's equivalent to `any(repeat[i]==repeat[i+1] for i in range(len(repeat)-1))`

Answer (score -1):

```
def isDup(arrayList):   
  x={}
  for i in arrayList:
    if i in x:
      return True
    x[i]=1
  return False
```

Comment: Why not just use a `set` instead of a dict, if your values have no meaning? Then, how is that different from OP's code?